# non-static method putExtra and cannot find symbol method

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a PHP developer but today I need to face the Android Studio.

I want to send an input text to another activity. But I had some errors:

> error: non-static method putExtra(String,String) cannot be
>   referencedfrom a static context error: cannot find symbol method
>   StartActivity(Intent)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.proj.proj";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, main.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    Intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    StartActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

what is wrong?

Comment: @Selvin inexperienced OP makes typo and you send him on a wild goose chase to figure out the difference between a static and non-static method. Not nice :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use proper instance of `intent` not `Intent`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  EditText editText;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main);
  }

  public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, main.class);

    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra("com.proj.proj", message);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Selvin, sorry man, looks like someone is stocked me from morning. Downvoted and Downvoted always.

Comment: Don't you worry the serial downvotes are automaticaly revers

Comment: `StartActivity(intent);` is still giving me an error

Comment: it's `startActivity()` (with a small **s**)

Comment: @RickJoe, yep, mistake was capital `S`, updated my answer. Use `startActivity()`

Comment: oh, I hate this case sensitive thing! kkk thank you friends!